# Convexity of Log of determinants ratio

Tags: convex-analysis, positive-definite

Let $\alpha$ be a positive variable and $A$ and $B$ be two positive definite matrices.
The function $f(\alpha)$ is defined as follows : $f(\alpha) = \text{log} \frac{\text{det}\{ A^{-1} + \,\alpha\,B\}}{\text{det}\{ [A \, + \, \alpha^{-1}\,B^{-1}]^{-1}\}}$

Is it possible to show that $f(\alpha)$ is a convex function?

P.S.
Numerically I can clearly see that $f(\alpha)$ is convex.